# SQL statement help

Tags: sql

Ok, so I am dealing with 4 tables here -

> Project, Members, Iterations and ProjectIterationMembers.

When I create new project details, I am writing them to the `Project` table and I am also specifying an iteration (`start date`, `end date` - a project consists of at least one iteration, but more iterations can be added afterwards). Members from the `Members` table are now written to the `ProjectIterationMembers` table as they are assigned to iterations.

The following SQL statement retrieves all of the projects for the company -

> project name, project manager and project status is displayed.

What I want to do, however, is only display the projects that the particular member is assigned to. When I try to pass MemberID, no results are retrieved.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Project.ProjectName), Project.ProjectID, Project.Status,   
Project.CompanyID, Project.StartDate, m.MemberID, 
m.FirstName + ' ' + m.LastName AS ProjectManager 
FROM Project, Member m, ProjectIterationMember, Iterations i WHERE 
m.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager' AND Project.CompanyID = '" + co_id + "' AND 
m.MemberID = ProjectIterationMember.MemberID AND i.ProjectIterationID = 
ProjectIterationMember.ProjectIterationID AND i.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID 
ORDER BY Project.StartDate DESC
```

The structure of my tables is as follows:

```
Project         Iterations               ProjectIterationMember    Member 
=============== ======================== ========================= ===========
ProjectID (PK)  ProjectIterationID (PK)  ProjectIterationMemberID  MemberID
CompanyID       ProjectID                ProjectIterationID        FirstName
ProjectName     StartDate                MemberID                  LastName
StartDate       EndDate
EndDate
Description
```

Comment: Does the Project Member ID you are passing is of CompanyRole = 'Project Manager' since you are only retrieving Proejct Managers.

Comment: I want to display the name of the project manager on that project, but I also want to ONLY display the projects assigned to the particular members logging in - so I need to pass memberID as a variable. How can I fix that?

Comment: You need to join the ProjectIterationMember table twice then, once to get the name of the manager, once to only get rows matching the logged in user. Please god please rewrite this with joins instead of a huge list of comma separated tables and conditions. You're torturing yourself and everyone else that has to read this code (like your coworkers/successors).

Comment: If you need project Manager as well then you need another join with Member for Project Manager retrieval and if Project Manager can be optional then you need left outer join :)

Comment: And I don't understand why ProjectName should be distinct?? This means if two projects with same name will not be repeated... You should make ProjectName as unique column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.*,
  m.MemberID,
  m.FirstName + ' ' + m.LastName AS ProjectManager
FROM
  Project p
INNER JOIN
  Iterations i
ON
  p.ProjectID = i.ProjectID
INNER JOIN
  ProjectIterationMember pim1
ON
  i.ProjectIterationId = pim1.ProjectIterationID
INNER JOIN
  Member m
ON
  pim1.ProjectIterationMemberID = m.MemberID
AND
  m.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager'
INNER JOIN
  ProjectIterationMember pim2
ON
  i.ProjectIterationId = pim2.ProjectIterationID
AND
  pim2.ProjectIterationMemberID = ?
WHERE
  p.CompanyID = ?
ORDER BY
  p.StartDate DESC
```

Comment: I had to modify this slightly, but it works now...many thanks Dan!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  p.ProjectName, 
  p.ProjectID, 
  p.Status,   
  p.CompanyID, 
  p.StartDate, 
  m1.MemberID, 
  m2.FirstName + ' ' + m2.LastName AS ProjectManager 
FROM 
  Project p INNER JOIN Iteration i on p.ProjectID = i.ProjectID
  INNER JOIN ProjectIterationMember pim ON i.ProjectIterationId = pim.ProjectIterationID
  INNER JOIN Member m1 ON pim.MemberID = m1.MemberID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Memember m2 ON pim.MemberID = m2.MemberID AND m2.CompanyRole = 'Project Manager'
WHERE 
  p.CompanyID = @coId AND 
  m.MemberID = @memberId
ORDER BY 
  Project.StartDate DESC
```

This will give the result even if the No PM is assigned... and passing memberid and companyid as parameters.